# Replace two combined letters with the same letters and a space in between with regular expression (regex) and php

Tags: php, regex, replace

I have a document where some words have been combined.

Fortunately, there is a pattern, for this instance. And the rate of false positives, where the pattern occurs in a legit way, is very low.

When words are combined, the first letter of the second word is a capital letter, because its a new sentence.
`wordsCombined` 
`combinedWords`
I need an efficient way to separate these words.

They can easily be identified with

`[a-z] [A-Z]`

but I am not sure how to replace them. Actually the way I could come up with is quite complicated.
It would be to find the pattern first pattern in the document, put it into a string then add a space and a dot after the first letter (position 1) then do a simple str_replace.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried.

Comment: Without code this question is not PHP relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression might be a point to start

```
([a-z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

and it would likely fail for some instances that we wish to replace or exclude.

In this [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kglRwx/1/), the expression is explained, if you might be interested.

#### Test

```
$re = '/([a-z][a-z]*)([A-Z][a-z]+)/m';
$str = 'some words before wordsCombined some words before combinedWords Alice and Bob some words before aWord some words before twoWrods';
$subst = '$1 $2';

echo preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

#### Output

```
some words before words Combined some words before combined Words Alice and Bob some words before a Word some words before two Wrods
```

Comment: Thank you Emma :) :)  surprisingly this ist the right answer. The other answers, including answers in the thread that is supposed to be a dupe, don't solve the issue, if, as stated in the question.. the other word is the beginning of a sentence. For your solution i could just add $subst = '$1.<br> $2';

Answer (score 0):

I am making a dynamic process, where we have to focus on 2 steps.

1) We have to find the position of the capital character for this we can use:

> **preg_match_all**

This function will give all the Capital character position in the array.

2) Then by using the for-each loop, we can add desire value before the capital letter.

> **substr_replace**

Here is one example we can test. We can also change the `$str` value:

```
$str = 'wordsCombined  combinedWords';
// Getting all matches in array
preg_match_all("/[A-Z]/", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$rep = $matches[0];
$index = 0;
$index_strlen = 0;
foreach($rep as $s)
{
  // Here I am making My start index dynamic 
   $index = $s[1]+$index_strlen;
   $str = substr_replace($str,' ', $index, 0);

  // After adding blank I am increasing string length by one.
   $index_strlen++;
}
echo $str;
```